# Backbone: Order of models inside a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

We created a Collection of models from an array as given below.  Our question is: will the Collection preserve the same order of elements/models as it was present in the original array? In other words, is the same order (of source array) guaranteed in Collection?

```
    var colorsData = [
    {
        name: 'red'
    },
    {
        name: 'blue'
    },
    {
        name: 'green'
    },
    .....
    .....
    .....
    //other colors
];

    var Color = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: 'white'
        }
    });

    var ColorCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Color
    });

    var colorCollection1 = new ColorCollection(colorsData); //creating a collection from the source array colorsData.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From all that I can gather, yes a `Collection` preserves the original order of elements.

You can read the annotated source for [collection](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-75) to see for yourself that it isn't magically shuffled time to time. Such functions as `at`, `unshift`, `pop`, `push`, etc. are quite clear indications of this.

You can read the annotated source for `parse`, which is used to parse the response from server after for example `fetch` -oprations:

```
parse: function(resp, xhr) {
  return resp;
},
```

To ascertain that whatever is passed on to your collection won't be shuffled anywhere. The resp will be passed on to the `add` -function that will process the response in natural order.

Comment: Yeah. If you throw an array of models into the collection, it gets added in that order. Generally the only time I can think of where this is not the default behavior is if you set a `comparator()` function. E.g. the comparator keeps your collection ordered by color hexidecimal, etc. When the comparator is defined, adding models will insert them in the correct position according to the sorting rule.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in http://backbonejs.org/#Collection

`collection.at(index)` retrieves models in insertion order.